# Influxdb does not close TCP connections

Tags: tcp, influxdb, influxdb-python

I connecting to my influxdb (`1.1.1.1:8086`) from my pc (`2.2.2.2`) to perform some queries. I find out, my server keeping the connections opened:

```
netstat -tpn | grep 8086
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:50839      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:51890      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:48478      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:56878      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:52680      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:52580      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:57184      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:61375      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:51220      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:34310      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:52282      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:49720      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:52946      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:52501      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:57278      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:36788      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:50687      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:64940      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:64949      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:48236      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:46754      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:50046      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:60312      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:55634      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:65141      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:51456      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:59572      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:49993      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:54233      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:50674      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:64182      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:8086     2.2.2.2:58076      ESTABLISHED 48554/influxd
```

When I tried it on my localhost, the connections decreased when I stop sending queries or data to save almost immediately. There is also no query performed by influxdb:

```
InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.0

> SHOW QUERIES
qid query        database duration status
--- -----        -------- -------- ------
670 SHOW QUERIES          537µs    running
```

How can I close this session in linux? How shoul I configure influxdb to close this sessions automatically(on local host I have default configuration).

Versions:
Python lib influxdb (5.1.0)
OS Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

PROGRAM:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import random

host = '1.1.1.1'
port = 8086
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
dbname = 'database'
client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)

json_body = [{"measurement": "TEST",
                "tags": {"Location": "local0"},
                "fields": {"Value": random.random()}}]
print(json_body)
client.write_points(json_body)
```

Comment: What is making those connections ?  Is it some code you wrote ? Can you post it ? What is your network setup between your client and the server ?

Comment: I added my program. What do you ean by network setup? I have ordered server from provider, this is not on my local network.

Comment: Well, you should call `client.close()` when you're done. If however the connections are still established when you exit your program, something else is going on that can't be resolved from the information here. Your IP addresses looks funky/odd-  so there might be things such as a firewall inbetween your client/server or other network related things that messes with your setup though.

Comment: If there would be some firewall, it should block it, but my server keep it in `established` state, isn't it problem on server side? Is there a way, how to close this connections from command line?

Comment: If the issue was purely on the server side, the connection state would not be "ESTABLISHED". Also remember that a firewall can do a lot more nasty things than just block connections.